# Is there any reason to consider the *bounded* derived category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

When derived categories were invented, people had to consider bounded variants to ensure that the "classical" resolutions worked in this new context. However, we now know that the derived category of a Grothendieck abelian category has K-injective resolutions (tag 079P on the Stacks Project). Also, in many (all?) interesting cases we also have K-flat or even K-projective resolutions allowing us to derive functors of all sorts. (I would also love to know if there's a general result about these resolutions akin to the one cited on the Stacks Project.)

**This seems to imply that there's no more reason to consider bounded derived categories.** Is there something that I'm missing?

(P.S.: While I'm interested in all sorts of reasons, I have one example that may be useful. In Neeman's approach to the Grothendieck duality (via Brown representability), which fundamentally needs the unbounded derived category, people still define the functor $f^!$ on a bounded derived category. I imagine that there's more than history to this.)

Comment: A reason (probably not the only one) will be that it is an important finiteness assumption. In module theory, sometimes you needs to consider only finite type modules, and if we want to extend this theory to a derived context, you will need to consider only bounded complexes (as unbounded one cannot be of finite type). For instance, Euler characteristic can only be defined on bounded complexes (with finite type cohomology). The "universal Euler characteristic" is the $K_0$, and thus K-theory also needs the bounded derived category.

Comment: @Roland wouldn't this same argument imply that in order to study quasi-coherent sheaves we need to consider bounded complexes with quasi-coherent cohomology? (Which is not the case.)

Comment: No. Quasicoherent sheaves are not analogous to finite modules; coherent sheaves are. And one does focus on bounded complexes of coherent sheaves.

Comment: @ZhenLin sure, but it is a finiteness condition nevertheless. Can you give more details on why we need to focus on the bounded derived category for coherent sheaves or finite modules? It is not so clear to me yet.

Comment: Quasicoherence is not a finiteness condition. Fact: the category of quasicoherent sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is equivalent to the category of all $A$-modules, not just finite $A$-modules. Coherence is a finiteness condition. Boundedness is also a finiteness condition. In fact, for noetherian $A$, the finitely presentable objects in the $(\infty, 1)$-category of chain complexes of $A$-modules are (up to quasi-isomorphism) the bounded complexes of finite $A$-modules.